# ng-model not working propertly with ng-options and array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive

After changing from ng-repeat in select options to ng-options i came across some problems. The issue is that ng-model sends whole array instead of the selected one.
I have an array with few values called sms

```
var sms = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
```

This is how i do it in HTML

```
<select id="sms-from" ng-options="s.id as s for s in sms" ng-selected="smsSender = s.id " ng-init="s = s.id " ng-model="sendSms.from">
</select>
```

This will make dropdown with all the values of sms array, and it should save the selected value to `$scope.sendSms.from` in my js file.

What it does is saves all the array instead of the selected values.

Were trying to switch from s.id to sms[0] in ng-selected and ng-init, but it gave the same result.

It worked fine when I was using ng-repeat inside option tag's but then the first value were blank so I've started using ng-options which is not a common way for me to do it.

Therefore i ask for you help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this doesn't even make sense.  your `ng-init` is trying to set the same value that the `ng-repeat` is setting, this is going to cause an issue. besides the fact that it's really not recommended to use `ng-init` except in special circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-selected="smsSender = s.id "` evaluates to `true` for all values in array(except for the one with id zero I guess), trye try `ng-selected="smsSender == s.id "` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- `var sms = ['1','2','3','4','5'];` should be `$scope.sms = ['1','2','3','4','5'];` as you are performing angular binding.
- `ng-options` syntax is incorrect. It should be `ng-options="s for s in sms"` as in the **`sms`** array there is no key with named as **`id`**.

Corrected **`<select>`** element syntax **:**

```
<select id="sms-from" ng-options="s for s in sms" ng-model="sendSms.from" ng-change="getVal(sendSms.from)">
</select>
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.sms = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
    
    $scope.getVal = function(val) {
      console.log(val);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id="sms-from" ng-options="s for s in sms" ng-model="sendSms.from" ng-change="getVal(sendSms.from)">
</select>
</div>
```